# Rails + Ember: Display a list/array of objects sorted by the Title string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I have this table model for an 'Artifact' object:

```
class CreateArtifacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :artifacts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.text :reason
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

With this model:

```
class Artifact < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :artifact_references, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And I retrieve and display this information in an EmberCli app with this handlebars code:

```
    {{#each artifact in model}}
    <div class="row">{{#link-to 'artifacts.details' artifact}}
        {{artifact.title}}
        {{/link-to}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
```

I want the results to be sorted alphabetically by the Title. So, right now it's just returning them in a slightly odd order--the API itself returns them in ID order, which of course makes sense. Like this:

```
{"artifacts":[
{"id":1,"title":"Key Performance Indicators","description":"Pre-stabilished criterias     to measure the making progress toward strategic goals or the maitenance of operational goals.","reason":"Measure the results and returns of the UX efforts.","artifact_reference_ids":[]},
{"id":2,"title":"Content Audit","description":"A content audit is the activity of checking all of the content on a website and compiling it into a big list.","reason":"This list of content will come in handy at various stages of the project. If you’re re-doing the information architecture, you’ll return to it again and again to remind yourself of the details of each page; Also, the big picture helps you define the content strategy.","artifact_reference_ids":[]},
```

But in the rendered page, it's doing a slight shift--2 of the Artifacts have 'has_many' records associated with them (artifacts_references). So those 2 appear at the top, basically rendering it as:

```
{"artifacts": [
{"id":24,...},
{"id":26,...},
{"id":1,...}
```

What I'd like is for it to display the results as:

```
A/B Test
Accessibility Analytics
Blueprint
Content Map
```

etc.

I tried adding

```
class Artifact < ActiveRecord::Base
    Artifact.order(:title)
    Has_many:artifact_references, dependent:destroy
end
```

To the model, and I tried adding

```
class ArtifactsController < Application Controller
    def query_params
      params.permit(:title,:description,:reason).order(:title)
    end
end
```

But neither of those work. I'm a newb. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you definitely sent me down the right path, and my co-worker helped me with the rest of it. It ended up looking like this, in the controller:

```
//controllers/artifacts.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    sortProperties: ['title'],
    sortAscending: true,
    filter:'',

    filteredContent: function(){
      var filter = this.get('filter');
      var rx = new RegExp(filter.replace(/\W/g, ''), 'gi');
      var rules = this.get('arrangedContent');

      return rules.filter(function(rule) {
        return rx.test(rule.get('title'));
      });

    }.property('arrangedContent', 'filter') 
    });

    // uses arrangedContent in the controller, which is the content as it has been sorted in the filter
```

And then this, in the hbs file:

```
    {{input value=filter placeholder="Filter List"}}
</div>
    {{#each artifact in filteredContent}}
    <div class="">{{#link-to 'artifacts.details' artifact}}
        {{artifact.title}}
        {{/link-to}}</div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a computed property on the Ember controller responsible for your Handlebars template. Sorting on the Rails side won’t help because Ember Data isn’t guaranteed to respect that ordering.

You don’t show the controller, but you can add properties like [the example from the guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-multiple-models-with-arraycontroller/#toc_sorting):

```
sortProperties: ['title'],
sortAscending: true
```

The `artifact`s in `model` will then come out sorted.

Comment: So I CLI'd a controller, looks like:
    `import Ember from 'ember';

    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
 sortProperties: ['title'],
 sortAscending: false
    });`
The problem is, that doesn't do anything, b/c the new controller, artifacts.js, doesn't know that which it is extending. I.e. in the example, it says `App.FooController = Ember.Controller.extend` but in mine it says `export default`...If I change it to match the example, I get `App not defined`. 
My application.js is `import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
 namespace: 'api'
});`

Comment: Ah, you didn’t say you were using Ember CLI. The guides haven’t been updated for that, sadly. The `App` business is going away, the `export default` thing is the new way.

Comment: The `sortProperties` and other sort-related properties are applicable for an `Ember.ArrayController`. Make your controller extend that rather than the base `Ember.Controller` and it should work.